# How do I expand selector width from center (or other efficient alternatives)?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a navigational bar (`#nav_bar`), which has the following CSS properties:

```
#nav_bar {
    background: url(../images/navbar.png) repeat-x;
    width: 100%; height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

It takes the width of `#wrap` which is `1024px` wide and has `margin: auto;`, however I would like to expand it so that it will fit all screen sizes `100%`. I attempted to set `width: 500%;` just to see what it would do, then I realized that it expands from the left -> right, rather than both ways from the center.

**So, what I'm asking is;**

> Is it possible to have an element expand from the center, then
>   perhaps I could set the     `max-width` property or use javascript to
>   find out the visitors screen resolution then   assign the width from
>   there; without major inefficiencies, i.e. extended load times/cross-browser compatibility issues?

[Just for reference, a link to the particular page I'm talking about](http://www.pixelation.me/travel_monster/)

Any answers will be greatly appreciated ;)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply move your `#nav_bar` out of the `#wrap`.

Alternatively you can make your `#nav_bar` have `position: absolute; left: 0px; width: 100%;` in CSS, that will work too.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [CSS3 Media Queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/), to find out about screen size of your clients.

If your `#nav-bar` is a **block-level element**, like a `div`, a `ul` or a `p` element, then it by default would take the whole width of its container. Thus you don't need to set `width: 100%;` there. Also, you can use `text-align: center;` to center align the content.

In your case, you can use **absolute positioning** with **overflow: visible** attribute, and set the width of the menu. Also, you may simply extract your `#nav-bar` out of the wrap, to let it take the whole space.

Comment: Cross browser compatibility :(. Thanks for the idea though.

Answer (score 0):

use `margin: auto`

you can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/s995c/4/

Comment: won't work, the navbar is inside a wrapper with width set lower than he'd like the navbar to have